# How to compare 2 json-lists with different length?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm getting two JSON-replies with different length: "data" and "data_out".

Short part of "data":

```
    "value":[
    {
    "A": "1112233"
    "B": "Abcdef"
    "C": "2019-04-26T10:00:00"
    "D": "http://aol.com/aaaa.mp3"
    "E": "880020030000"
    }
    ]
```

Then this block can repeat in "data" random times. 
The same in "data_out", but there is other date/time.

I need to make a file where are two JSON-lists will be sort by date and time. 
I do it with "while".

```
index_3 = 0
index_out_3 = 0
while index_3 < len(data['value']):
    while index_out_3 < len(data_out['value']):
        time_in = (data['value'][index_3]['C'])
        time_out = (data_out['value'][index_out_3]['C'])

        if time_in < time_out:
            #<put all info from 'data' to xls-file>
            index_3 += 1
        else:
            #<put all info from 'data_out' to xls-file>
            index_out_3 += 1
```

But I have a problem that "data" ends earlier than "data_out". Sometimes it is so, but sometimes "data_out" is longer than "data" and i have mistake:

```
time_in = (data['value'][index_3]['start_time'])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually need two while loops if you are going to use two separate index variables.

```
while index_3 < len(data['value']) and index_out_3 < len(data_out['value']):
    time_in = (data['value'][index_3]['C'])
    time_out = (data_out['value'][index_out_3]['C'])
    if time_in < time_out:
        <put all info from 'data' to xls-file>
        index_3 += 1
    else:
        <put all info from 'data_out' to xls-file>
        index_out_3 += 1
```

This ensures that your code will exit if any of the JSON lists reaches their end.
If you want to do additional work after exit, consider another condition either inside or outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you! Shame on me.

Comment: Everyone's gotta start somewhere. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If `data` and `data_out` have similar structure (as in your example),
you could chain both lists together and then simply sort by time.

```
from itertools import chain

# chain lists together, e.g. chain([2, 1], [4, 3]) => iterable(2, 1, 4, 3)
result = chain(data["value"], data_out["value"])
result = sorted(result, key=lambda d: d["C"])
# <put all info from 'result' to xls-file>
```

Comment: Keys in [values] have a little bit different names. "Start_time" and "starttime", for example.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/xlwings/jsondiff is too cool and I rely upon it heavily. Thanks to the creator of this package

This is a pure excerpt from the code home page readme

> > > from jsondiff import diff
> > >
> > > diff({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 3, 'c': 4})

{'c': 4, 'b': 3, delete: ['a']}

> > > diff(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

{insert: [(3, 'd')]}